# Will Blender Sensei Format work MacOS and Win10?

Tags: add-on

I have a computer with Mac OS Sierra and I also have a laptop running Win 10

Has the Blender Sensei Format addon updated to work with both operating systems?

Comment: Do you mean MacOs Sierra? I think you can run addons on either platform

Comment: Addons work regardless of operating system. Here is how to install it on osx https://blendersensei.com/forums/topic/sensei-format-on-mac/

Comment: Thank You sir SenseiFormat versions of Blender working side by side with default Blender

Comment: I added my comment as an answer since it it solved your problem.

Comment: Do you know how to run default blender and sensei format addon blender at
the same time for comparison? I am a Mac on os serrea

Comment: if you have two computers, you could just launch one of them with sensei and the other one without sensei

Answer (score 1):

Addons work regardless of operating system. Here is how you can install Sensei Format on MacOS: blendersensei.com/forums/topic/sensei-format-on-mac

Comment: Thank You Sir
for me I have a iMac and PC laptop
But since I have been reading on different threads over the net 
it seem that a lot of people are having trouble with install this add on into blender on Mac 
so I wait a while until they have that work out 
But me as well in Windows 10 64 bit 
I just follow what he said and 
do 
From his very well done videos

Comment: Installing Sensei Format

https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLS24VPXMziw2bmTkMdgd0crwU2vYH5Bzu&params=OAFIAVgC&v=q9bkFai-BaM&mode=NORMAL


Updating Sensei Format

https://m.youtube.com/watch?list=PLS24VPXMziw2bmTkMdgd0crwU2vYH5Bzu&params=OAFIAVgD&v=jvWkqR3VV8Q&mode=NORMAL


I end up following these as he said

Comment: And went all good

Comment: Do You use this add on?